# Complex GROUP BY using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am familiar with simple `GROUP BY` operation in `LINQ`. But I have a complex scenario. I need to convert the `CostPageRow` records into `CostPageSelection` domain objects using group by. How can we get the domain objects from the List?

Note: The group by that I wrote above does not give List. I am not sure how to write it. The CostPageSelection has a list inside it.

```
List<CostPageRow> costPageRows = searchDAL
    .GetAllCostPages(contextObject, searchCriteria);


var orderGroups = costPageRows
     .GroupBy(x => new { 
         x.CostPage, 
         x.Description, 
         x.BillTypeDirect,
         x.BillTypeWarehouse,
         x.OrderType,
         x.Vendor,
         x.VendorID 
     })
     .Select(y => new CostPageParent { 
           CostPage = y.First().CostPage 
     })
     .ToList();
```

Result from Stored Procedure

```
public class CostPageRow
{
    //CostPage Parent

    public string CostPage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    public string BillTypeDirect { get; set; }
    public string BillTypeWarehouse { get; set; }
    public string OrderType { get; set; }

    //Item Chilld
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string BrandCode { get; set; }
    public string PackSize { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Model

```
public class CostPageSelection
{
    public CostPageParent CostPageParent { get; set; }
    public List<ItemChild> ChildItems { get; set; }
}


//CostPageParent
public class CostPageParent
{
    public int? SelectedCostPageID { get; set; }
    public string CostPage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string VendorID { get; set; }
    public string BillTypeDirect { get; set; }
    public string BillTypeWarehouse { get; set; }
    public string OrderType { get; set; }
}

//ItemChild
public class ItemChild
{
    public int? SelectedItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string BrandCode { get; set; }
    public string PackSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky. The group by that I wrote above does not give List<CostPageSelection>. I am not sure how to write it. The CostPageSelection has a list inside it.

Comment: @Groo Can you please post your code? My belief is, grouping is needed. Since what is common is CostPageParent. And we have a  List<ItemChild>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question, it appears that your database contains a flattened hierarchy of your parent-child relationships, and it would be much better if the database schema was normalized to avoid data duplication: in other words, each `CostPageRow` row should contain a *reference* to a different table containing the related `CostPageParent` instance (but I presume you already have a running database and this is not an option).

To solve your current problem as it is, you need to extract the properties which define a single group out of each `CostPageRow` instance (these properties will form a new `CostPageParent` instance), then create groups using these `CostPageParent` instances as unique keys, and finally project the groups to new instances of `CostPageSelection` (each with a unique `CostPageParent` key).

You need to modify your code to use the `IGrouping<T>.Key` property to get the group key, after you create it:

```
var groups = costPageRows
    .GroupBy(x => new CostPageParent()
        {
            CostPage = x.CostPage,
            Description = x.Description,
            BillTypeDirect =  x.BillTypeDirect,
            BillTypeWarehouse = x.BillTypeWarehouse,
            OrderType = x.OrderType,
            Vendor = x.Vendor
        }, 
        new CostPageParentEqualityComparer())
    .Select(y => new CostPageSelection
        {
            CostPageParent = y.Key,
            ChildItems = y.Select(i => 
                new ItemChild()
                { 
                    BrandCode = i.BrandCode,
                    ItemDescription = i.ItemDescription,
                    ItemID = i.ItemID,
                    PackSize = i.PackSize
                })
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

Note that you need to specify the `IEqualityComparer<CostPageParent>` implementation to make the grouping work property:

```
class CostPageParentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CostPageParent>
{
    public bool Equals(CostPageParent x, CostPageParent y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        return 
            x.BillTypeDirect == y.BillTypeDirect &&
            x.BillTypeWarehouse == y.BillTypeWarehouse &&
            ...
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CostPageParent obj)
    {
        var x = 31;
        x = x * 17 + obj.BillTypeDirect.GetHashCode();
        x = x * 17 + obj.BillTypeWarehouse.GetHashCode();
        ...
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. It works.. Can you please explain why we need the GetHashCode logic? The grouping is working fine even if I return a hard coded values as the result of GetHashCode.

Comment: @Groo `GroupBy` is implemented, internally, using a hash based data structure (Either `Dictionary` or similar), so you most certainly **do** need to have a proper `GetHashCode` implementation of a type if you want to use `GroupBy` on it.

Comment: @Lijo It works because the rules for proper implementation of `GetHashCode` say that all objects that are equal according to `Equals` *must* have the same hash code.  It is best to ensure that unequal objects are less likely to have the same hash (some instances of it are inevitable).  The more objects that share a hash the worse the data structure will perform.  If all objects have the same has code it will *work*, but it will be *very* slow.  See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @Servy: yes, you're right, I don't know what I was thinking since that's the only reasonable way to implement grouping in `O(n)` time. Of course Lijo's code worked with constant hash values, but the performance went quadratic. I saw the comment and immediately started writing the generic answer about why it's good to implement it in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var orderGroups = costPageRows
 .GroupBy(x => new { 
     x.CostPage, 
     x.Description, 
     x.BillTypeDirect,
     x.BillTypeWarehouse,
     x.OrderType,
     x.Vendor,
     x.VendorID 
 })
 // The following statement is basically a let statement from query expression
 .Select(y => new {
      y, 
      first = y.First()
 })
 // What happens next is projection into the CostPageSelection type using z.first
 // and then all the grouped items in z are projected into the ItemChild type
 .Select(z => new CostPageSelection {
      new CostPageParent { 
          z.first.CostPage, 
          // other props 
          ChildItems = z.Select(i => new ItemChild {
              i.ItemID,
              // other props 
          }).ToList()
 })
 .ToList();
```